# How can I implement odd-even sorting in C# using threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sorting, parallel-processing

I am practicing about threads and concurrency in C# and tried to implement the basic odd-even sort algorithm using a thread for even and another for odd sorting.

```
static bool Sort(int startPosition, List<int> list)
        {
            bool result = true;
            do
            {
                for (int i = startPosition; i <= list.Count - 2; i = i + 2)
                {
                    if (list[i] > list[i + 1])
                    {
                        int temp = list[i];
                        list[i] = list[i + 1];
                        list[i + 1] = temp;
                        result = false;
                    }
                }
            } while (!result);
            return result;
        }
```

While the main method is like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool isOddSorted = false;
            bool isEvenSorted = false;

            List<int> list = new List<int>();
            while (list.Count < 15)
            {
                list.Add(new Random().Next(0, 20));
            }

            var evenThread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                isEvenSorted = Sort(0, list);
            });
            evenThread.Start();

            var oddThread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                isOddSorted = Sort(1, list);
            });
            oddThread.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                if (isEvenSorted && isOddSorted)
                {
                    foreach (int i in list)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(i);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
```

Understandably, the loop in Sort method works forever because the result variable is never set to true. However the way it works manages to sort the list. It just doesn't break at any time.[image]

However the moment I add a "result = true" to the first line of do-scope of Sort function, the sorting messes up. [image]

I couldn't figure out how to fix this.

Comment: Is your goal just to write a multithreaded odd-even sort implementation that works correctly, or you also want that implementation to be faster at sorting numbers than the original single-thread implementation?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do odd-even sort easily in a multi-threaded manner. Why?
Because the odd-even sort is in essence the repetition of two sorting passes (the odd and the even pass), with any subsequent pass **depending** on the result of the preceding pass. You cannot run two passes in parallel/concurrently in practical terms, as each pass has to **follow** each other.

There are of course ways to employ multi-threading, even with odd-even-sort, although that wouldn't probably make much practical sense. For example, you could divide the list into several partitions, with each partition being odd-even-sorted independently. The sorting of each partition could be done in a multi-threaded manner. As a final step it would require merging the sorted partitions in a way that would result in the fully sorted list.

(By the way, that you eventually get a sorted list if you only let the `do` `while` loops in your `Sort` method run many, many times is just that given enough time, even with "overlapping" concurrent passes you reach eventually a sorted list, but maybe not with all the same numbers from the original list. Because given enough repetions of the loop, eventually the elements will be compared with each other and shuffled to the right positions. However, since you have not synchronized list access, you might lose some numbers from the list, being replaced with duplicates of other numbers, depending on the runtime behavior and timing of list accesses between the two threads.)

Comment: *"...you could divide the list into several partitions, with each partition being odd-even-sorted independently."*: According to the Wikipedia article about the [odd–even sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odd%E2%80%93even_sort), it's a relatively slow algorithm, so it's probably not a good idea to odd-even-sort each partition, considering that more efficient sort algorithms exist.

Answer (score -1):

Look at your `result` variable and the logic you have implemented with regard to `result`.

The outer `do ... while (!result)` loop will only exit when `result` is being *true*.

Now imagine your inner `for` loop finds two numbers that need swapping. So it does and swaps the numbers. And sets `result` to *false*. And here is my question to you: After `result` has been set to *false* when two numbers have been swapped, when and where is `result` ever being set to *true*?

Also, while you sort each the numbers on even list positions, and each the numbers on odd positions, your code does not do a final sort across the entire list. So, basically, if after doing the even and odd sorting, a larger number on an even position `n` is followed by a smaller number on odd position `n+1`, your code leaves it at that, leaving the list essentially still (partially) unsorted...

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to modify non-thread safe collection across threads.
Even if the assumption is good - you are using basic swap in `Sort` method (but you did not implement it entirely correct), you have to take under account that while one of the threads is doing the swap, other one could swap a value that is being in `temp` variable in this exact moment.
You would need to familiarize ourself with either [locks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) and/or [thread-Safe Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/).

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen my understanding about the odd-even sorting algorithm, as described by the OP in the question, is that one thread sorts all the odd numbers and a second thread sorts all the even numbers. And eventually the two sorted subsets are merged by a single thread. My understanding might be wrong. It seems that the [Odd–even sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odd%E2%80%93even_sort) is more involved than that. But in any case, my assumption is that the odd-even sort is a lock-free algorithm. This answer suggests using locking or synchronized collections, hence my downvote.

Comment: Odd-even sort would be fine, but in this case when sorting one thread can move a value when the other one is in a `temp` state - best case it will be just an sub-optimal sorter. There is also case to be made that `List` is a non-thread safe collection - while reading from it by multiple threads is more or less ok, modifying it is definitely not - So I'm going to stick with my answer for this one.

Comment: quain you could try to implement a parallel odd-even sort algorithm based on your idea of `lock`ing on every swap, or using a concurrent collection (a `ConcurrentDictionary` I guess). If you manage to implement something that is even slightly faster than a single-threaded odd-even sort, and it's based on one of these two ideas, and it's not using any other sorting algorithm internally, I promise to award an 100 points bounty on this answer. My expectation is that any such parallel implementation will be many times slower than the non-parallel one. It won't be even close.

Comment: You are right, there is 95% probability that parallel algorithm in this case, even on large data set would be slower - but I never said that it would not be. All my answers are directed at Op's code - He is already using multiple threads with a non-thread safe collection among other things (algorithm itself is not fully implemented correctly) - nothing else. I never stated that going multithreaded would be faster.

Comment: I think that going faster is an implicit expectation when going multithreading. I just asked the OP about it to make it sure.